# Encapsulating CSS code in javascript plugin

Tags: css

I'm writing JS plugin which will be placed in several different websites. Those websites are using different styling, some Bootstrap, some Bulma and some just custom styles.

My plugin is generating DOM elements like divs, inputs, selects. I want to style those elements on my own. How to make this plugin look the same in any website which it will be embed?

Comment: What have you tried? Which tutorial you plan to follow? We need something not just requests. By the way, why does it sound like you're trying to make some sort of phishing scam?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe creating Shadow DOM elements would help. Then you will be able to add your custom DOM elements and they will not be affected by whatever is outside. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM